# how to pass null arguments to base class constructor c#

Tags: c#, .net

I have two class which extends a base class and baseclass takes 5 argument but in two of my derived class I don't want to pass 5 arguments . can anyone tell me how to bypass it . I'm new at this . please help

Example :

**BaseClass**

```
    public abstract class xyz<TOrderView, Component1, Component2, Component3, Component4>
```

**Derived class 1**

```
    public class abcdef : xyz<IOrderView, Component1, Component2, Component3>
```

**Derived class 2**
        public class rdesa : xyz

Class abcdef doesn't need 5 argument but class rdesa need to pass 5 argument . Can anyone tell me how to pass null as argument to base class .
I'm new at this please help .

Comment: The template arguments are types, they can’t be null. I wonder if there’s a design problem here. A more descriptive example would clarify that

Comment: Here's a useful article on Base classes and constructors: http://jonskeet.uk/csharp/constructors.html

Comment: You cannot do that. This is how inheritance works. Also you should go and read Design Patterns where they say to use `Composition over Inheritance` for this very reason. That means Interfaces will be far better suited here. In short.. Unless you know exactly how to work with inheritance.. then DO NOT DO IT!

Answer (score 1):

Long answer:

You need to re-examine your inheritance hierarchy after reading up on the Liskov substitution principle.

Short answer:
You can pass some acceptable type to the base class constructor.

```
public class abcdef<IOrderView, Component1, Component2, Component3> 
    : xyz<IOrderView, Component1, Component2, Component3, object>
```